# Add a number to list in a specified index range

Tags: python, list

Input

```
l = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to add 1 to index range from 2 to 3

so output should be

```
l = [0, 0, 2, 3, 3]

l[2:3] = l[2:3] + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `numpy`, it's quite optimized and uses C/C++ loops under the hood, so it's blazingly fast:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> b = np.array(a)
>>> b[2:4] += 1
>>> b
array([0, 0, 2, 3, 3])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for i in range(2, 4):
    l[i] += 1
```

Comment: without for loop it isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution can make use of list-comprehension:
`l[2:4] = [x+1 for x in l[2:4]]`

Answer (score -1):

For a hilariously overblown solution:

```py
from operator import add

l = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
deltas = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

result = list(map(add, l, deltas))
```

note that this does not modify `l`, but creates a new list in `result`